# Clipboard change is fired after running program

Tags: autohotkey

I am using this simple script:

```
#SingleInstance force

OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")

ClipChanged(Type) {
    MsgBox ClipChanged
}

ConnectToServer(ip)
{
    password := "foo"
    Run "C:\Program Files\TightVNC\tvnviewer.exe" -host=%ip% -password=%password%
}

LCtrl & F3::
    ConnectToServer("192.168.1.1")
return
```

My question is: why after pressing `Ctrl + F3` I can see message "ClipChanged"? I did not changed clipboard, so why `ClipChanged` is fired?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Have you verified the problem with this specific snippet of code?

Comment: See [OnClipboardChange --> Func --> Return Value](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnClipboardChange.htm#Func).

Comment: @D.Pardal yes, I have

Comment: Maybe `tvnviewer.exe` changes the clipboard...?

Comment: @D.Pardal You're right! It does! Is there anything I can do about it?